# Is adding 'Attribute' to the attribute class name a breaking change?

Tags: c#, .net, attributes

I came across the following C# code:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = false)]
public class Marker : Attribute
{
}
```

We use SonarLint and one [of it's rules](http://www.sonarlint.org/visualstudio/rules/index.html#version=5.9.0.992&ruleId=S3376) that say that the class should be prefixed with the word `Attribute`.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = false)]
public class MarkerAttribute : Attribute
{
}
```

I was wondering is changing the name `Marker` to `MarkerAttribute` a breaking change? Since when using the attribute, you are allowed to skip the `Attribute` part. On the other hand, when using the attribute in code, you need the whole name, so than it will be breaking.

If this is considered a breaking change, what would be the best way to deal with this? Because this:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = false)]
public class MarkerAttribute : Attribute { }
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = false)]
public class Marker : MarkerAttribute { }
```

will give the following compile error when used:

> CS1614    'Marker' is ambiguous between 'Marker' and 'MarkerAttribute';
>   use either '@Marker' or 'MarkerAttribute'

Comment: From an API-perspective it is of course a breaking change as *every* class-renaming. Thus you´d have to recompile all your depending assemblies as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attributes are metadata. On their own attributes do nothing. Attributes become useful when some code reads them. In order to read attribute value, the code should use attribute class name. E.g. via [`GetCustomAttribute<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194292(v=vs.110).aspx) call:

```
Maker maker = yourType.GetCustomAttribute<Maker>();
```

So renaming an attribute class is a breaking change. In order to pass compliance checking rule, you should rename attribute class. No options here.

---

Note that if you'll inheritance here:

```
public class Marker : MarkerAttribute { }
```

then you'll end up with exactly same SonarLint rule broken - you will get two attribute classes, one of which will be noncompliant.